# Problem: Series of function and uniform convergence of them

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence, lipschitz-functions

my professor gave me this problem that I can't solve at all.. is there anyone who can help me?

Assume that $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a (globally)
Lipschitz continous function

i.e. $\exists L$ : $\forall x,y$ $\epsilon\mathbb{R}$ $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|\leq L|x-y|$

1) Demonstrate that if $f_{n}$ is a succession of continous functions
that converges uniformly to $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
so

$\phi\circ f_{n}$ converges uniformly to $\phi\circ f$

2) What can we say about the succession $\phi\circ f$ , is we assume
that $\phi$ is a lipschitz function but just locally and $f$ is
bounded?

3) What can we say about the succession $\phi\circ f$ , if we only
assume that $\phi$ is a continous function?

Let me know if there's someone who can help me! thanks a lot

Comment: I'm confident that if you write out the definitions you should be able to prove 1). Show some effort!

Comment: Yes, the first point is really easy, I just want to write down everything my prof. gave me.. My problem is that I can't make the other 2 points..

Comment: The second one is the same as the first because you can take $x,y$ to br min f max f

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you explain me better the second and the third point?